# Apache 2.4 SetEnv not working

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables

I'm trying to set a local environment variable to test my PHP app on a windows machine. I added `SetEnv API_HOST /foo/bin` in the file `C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf` and restarted the server by executing `httpd -k restart` at the command line.

In my app I check the variable `$_SERVER['API_HOST']` and I always get null and it isn't null in the development server since the environment variable is set there.

I also tried to create confs files, set the env variable and include the files in the httpd.conf, but also doesn't work.

I was expecting this to be straight forward, but it seems something is missing. Any idea why it isn't working?

Thanks.

Comment: If your app is configured in a vhost using a different file you need to add the `SetEnv` there

Comment: My app is configured in ``C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf`` and I added the following: ``DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs/<app>"
<Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs/<app>"> ... </Directory>`` without success.

Comment: Is mod_env enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, forgot to answer earlier. It started working with the following in the httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "path/to/project-root"
  ServerName localhost
  SetEnv API_HOST /foo/bin
</VirtualHost>
```

And restart the apache server by going to the path `C:\Apache24\bin` on the cmd and execute `httpd -k stop` and `httpd -k start`. I tried `httpd -k restart` several times before and didn't work, don't know why.

Cheers